# Pytorch: Using Adam Optimizer for a custom variable/Model with requires_grad?

Tags: pytorch

Have the following model as follows:

```
import torch.nn as nn
class DefaultModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, guess, K):
        super(DefaultModel, self).__init__()

        #guess = [-0.7541, -0.044,  0.0916,  1.5914, -0.0017,  1.4991]
        self.T = torch.tensor(guess).unsqueeze(0)
        self.T.requires_grad = True

        self.K = K

    def forward(self, datapoints, draw):
        Mat = pose_vec2mat(self.T).squeeze(0)
        loss = stuff(datapoints)
        return loss
```

Normally with hand coded gradient descent I would do something like this:

```
model = DefaultModel(guess, K)
gamma = torch.tensor([5e-5, 5e-5, 5e-5, 2e-5, 2e-5, 2e-5])
for i in range(0, 10000):
    
    loss = model(datapoints, draw=[1, 0,5,6])
    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        model.T = model.T - gamma * model.T.grad
    model.T.requires_grad = True
```

However, if I want to do this using Adam Optimizer:

```
model = DefaultModel(guess, K)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
```

It crashes with `ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list` How can I get my variable T which requires grad in the parameter list?

Answer (score 0):

`torch.nn.Module.parameters()` gives you the parameters (`torch.nn.parameter.Parameter`) of the torch module, which only contains the parameters of the submodules in the module.
So since `self.T` is just a tensor, not a `nn.Module`, it's not included in `model.parameters()`.

As far as I know `torch.nn.Module.parameters()` doesn't do much except returning the parameters. So if your forward logic is correct, I think this will work fine.

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.T, lr=1e-5)
```